# Android invoke activity after screen is unlocked

Tags: android, service, android-activity, unlock

I'm looking to write an android app that invokes a screen/activity after some one has entered the default android unlock pattern correctly.

I'm assuming that the best way to do this is run a service in the background that waits for this activity then on detecting this invokes an activity screen displaying the information?

Does that sound like a sensible way of doing things or is there a better way?

Also if anyone can point me at examples of this that would be amazing.

Cheers

Ric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for the action [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) 
`ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is fired after `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, usually when the keyguard is gone.

So create a handler and wait for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`. When you got it, implement what you want for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver to recieve boot_complete action then create a service and start it from onRecieve of broadcastReceiver .

A good tutorial [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/)